# Camelize up to a certain part of a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have:

```
s = "like_so__case"
```

`camelize` gives this:

```
s.camelize # => "LikeSoCase"
```

I'm looking for conversion up to a double underscore `__` to get:

```
"LikeSo__case"
```

How can I camelize only up to a certain part of a string?

Comment: Is the string guaranteed to contain two adjacent underscores?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest option is to gsub part of your string.

```
'like_so__case'.gsub(/(.*?)(__.*)/) { "#{$1.camelize}#{$2}" }
#=> "LikeSo__case"
```

UPDATE

Cleaner and faster way arising from comments.

```
'like_so__case__h'.sub(/(.*?)(?=__)/, &:camelize)
#=> "LikeSo__case__h"
```

Comment: Since you only want to replace the first occurrence, you should use `sub` instead of `gsub`. And you could use a positive lookahead to avoid the global variables, e.g. `sub(/(.*?)(?=__)/, &:camelize)`

Comment: Which Ruby Version are you using? camelize throws the error for me.

Comment: @Stefan So it's available in Rails? Not in pure Ruby?

Comment: @Rajagopalan yes, `camelize` is also used in the question (which has a  `ruby-on-rails` tag)

Comment: If you want avoid lazy quantifiers (`.*?`) you can change the regex into `/([^_]|_(?!_))*(?=__)/` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "like_so__case"
 => "like_so__case" 
s.split('__', 2).tap { |s| s[0] = s[0].camelize }.join('__')
 => "LikeSo__case"
```

You of course could wrap it in string method

Answer (score 1):

For getting this `LikeSo__case`, we can do like:

```
s="like_so__case"
s.split('__').tap { |s| s[0] = s[0].camelize }.join('__')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description on the demand is not so clear.

From your excepted result, I understand it as 'camelize a part of string until a pattern'. I should note one thing first that `camelize` is not part of Ruby's standard library of class `String`. `ActiveSupport::Inflector` provides it.

So if you want to just camelize each part divided by a pattern, use `str.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join('_')`. In your case, it returns `'Like_So__Case'`.

Ruby's `String` has another instance method named `partition`, which splits the string into three parts (an array):

- Part before the pattern
- The pattern
- Part after the pattern

So `str.partition('__').tap { |a| a[0] = a[0].split('_').map(&:capitalize).join }.join` should be your answer in plain Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

No need of relying on `camelize`. Simply, this:

```
"like_so__case"
.gsub(/_?([a-z])([a-z]*)(?=.*__)/i){$1.upcase + $2.downcase}
# => "LikeSo__case"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def camelize(s)
  for i in 0..s.size-2 do
    if s[i] == "_" and s[i+1] == "_" 
      next
    elsif s[i] == "_" and s[i+1] != "_" and s[i-1] != "_"
      s[i+1] = s[i+1].upcase
      s[i] = ""
    else
      next
    end
  end
  return s
end
```

Use this method to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "like_so__case"

i = s.index('__')
  #=> 7
s.tap { |s| s[0,i] = s[0,i].camelize }
  #=> LikeSo__case
```

The last line could be replaced by two lines:

```
s[0,i] = s[0,i].camelize
s
```

If the original string is not to be mutated write

```
s.dup.tap { |s| s[0,i] = s[0,i].camelize }
```